# Saving an actual state of the application

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-sqlite

I'm developing an application in which one of the function is a voice recording. User can choose among of 4 categories. Each category consists of strings populated from an array. One string / word is displayed at the time on the screen. Once it's recorded he or she can swipe a screen to see the next word. The next word is of course next item from an array. During the runtime I keep track of the actual position by saving it in the variables. However when a user quits an application of course all the variables are reseted and when come back, he or she has to start over again from the first word. I know that I have to persist the current position in the file or db to be able to remember the last state. My question is what is the best choice in this case of saving it? Besides of the current position each user will also have assign a number (kind of feedback on ebay or reputation in stackoverflow) that I would also have to keep track of. Is shared preferences a good choice or maybe it's better to create a SQLite db? Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: You can save this information a lot of differnt ways, read the Developer's Guide on [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know the choices but I thought that maybe somebody with greater experience might advise me the most appropriate way of doing it in this particular case since.

Comment: In general, for anything more complex than random strings/numbers, you should use a SQLite DB. If you think you can store the whole state of your app with just strings and numbers, then preferences might be fine.